# IntelliJ14でGolang PluginがGOROOT, GOPATHを認識しない

Tags: go, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 14 で[golang plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin)を使おうとしているのですが、以下のエラーが消せません。

類似の問題がネットで多数ありましたが、どれも解決されませんでした。

[image: errors]

当方環境

- MacOSX 10.10.3
- `echo $GOROOT` -> `/Users/otiai10/.go` （ソースから入れたもの）
- `echo $GOPATH` -> `/Users/otiai10/proj/go`
- sudo launchctl getenvでも同様のpathが得られます

大変お恥ずかしいのですが、ご助言いただけると幸いですmm

Comment: 「どれも解決されませんでした」と書かれていますが、具体的にどのような解決方法を試しましたか？

Comment: すみません、言葉足らずでした。

- http://qiita.com/kaiinui/items/433eb86c022ffcad0bea
- http://marmotte.pyrites.jp/blog/2015/01/02/idea-and-golang-on-yosemite/
    - `sudo launchctl setenv GOROOT`
- http://qiita.com/adarah_g/items/85d12583386dc19f6c4e
    - `/etc/launchd.conf`の編集
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/sqBt7APUL1Y
- http://pivotallabs.com/setting-google-go-plugin-intellij-idea-13-os-x-10-8-5/
    - （英語がよくわからなかったのでjp.stackoverflowへ来た次第です...）

上記の日本語ドキュメントについては実際に操作しました。英語ドキュメントについては、理解している自信が無かったため試しておりません。

Comment: ご助力ありがとうございました！解決いたしましたので、今まとめております

Answer (score 1, accepted):

カスタムでplugin repositoryを参照する必要がありました。詳細は以下にまとめました。
http://otiai10.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/06/02/224636

お騒がせして申し訳ありませんでした。